# ActivityNotFoundException while using startActivity(Intent)

Tags: java, android, android-intent, android-activity, logcat

Here's the error, referring to where I call startActivity(Intent):

```
`05-17 01:40:37.918: E/AndroidRuntime(12997):android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: 
Unable to find explicit activity class {/com.rhombi.Menu}; have you declared 
this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?
```

Here's how I use startActivity(Intent) in com.rhombi.Intro:

```
startActivity(iMenu);
```

Here's how I declare it earlier, in the same class:

```
public Intent iMenu = new Intent(this, Menu.class);
```

Here's how I declare it all in my manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.rhombi"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="18" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:screenOrientation="portrait"
    android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen" >
    <activity
        android:name=".Intro"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".Menu"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
    </activity>
</application>
</manifest>
```

I've searched through a TON of other questions about this and I can't seem to figure out what the issue is. The one thing that makes my issue unique is that little forward slash when it tells me that it's unable to find the explicit activity class ("{/com.rhombi.Menu}"). That never showed up in my searches, but I appear to be doing everything right.

Comment: Is the Activity named `Menu` spelled right and does it exist in the same package `com.rhombi`?

Comment: have register your activity in manifest?

Comment: @ДмитрийИвановичМенделеев yes op has `<activity android:name=".Menu"`

Comment: Yes, the class exists as com.rhombi.Menu.

Comment: Remove it and add again. If all else fails and you don't wanna waste more time, create a new activity and simply paste the code in it.

Comment: What looks suspicious is that the package name in the `ComponentInfo` is empty here: `{/com.rhombi.Menu}` - there's just the class name. What was the `this` you passed to `Intent` ctor as `Context`?

Comment: @laalto Thanks, that was it. I was simply declaring the intent in the wrong space.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There was something wrong with the `this` you passed as a `Context` to the `Intent` constructor, as evidenced by the empty package name in `ComponentInfo` `{/com.rhombi.Menu}` - there's just the class name.

Answer (score 0):

try changing

`android:name=".Menu"` to `android:name="{package name}.Menu"`

Comment: I already tried this, as well as getting rid of the period. It didn't work.

Comment: @JohnO. try clean and build and also post `Menu.java`. it seems ok

Comment: ur android app will contain 2 androidManifest.xml, 1 inside bin folder, one outside.. hope u r nt modifying the androidmanifest.xml inside bin folder one..verify it once..coz everything seems ok here..